# Conic chords projected by point $P$ form a quadrilateral whose vertex pairs are collinear with $P$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

[image: pencil intersects conic]

Starting with a conic $c$, a point $P$ not on $c$, and points $D,E,F,G$ on $c$, let $D',E',F',G'$ be the second points of intersection of the lines $PD,PE,PF,PG$ with $c$.

Let
$$
\begin{align}
L &= DE\cdot FG \\
M &= D'E'\cdot F'G' \\
N &= FG\cdot F'G' \\
O &= DE\cdot D'E' \\
Q &= DE\cdot F'G' \\
R &= D'E'\cdot FG 
\end{align}
$$

It's easy to show that $O,N$ are on the polar of $P$ wrt $c$.  But here's the question:

> show that the triples $P,Q,R$ and $P,L,M$ are respectively collinear.

It's possible to find a projective transformation that takes $P$ to a point at infinity and $c$ to a circle.  Then the lines $DD',EE',\dots$ are parallel and it's easy to show the proposition.  But I'd like a proof that doesn't use that trick.

The question arises from a simplification of 3D configuration, where $c$ is a sphere (or quadric) and two cones with apex $P$ cut $c$ in four planes.  These planes intersect in lines analogous to $L,M,\dots,R$.  I'm hoping a projective proof in 2D will 'lift' to a proof in 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perspectivity is a projective transformation fixing the points of a line $p$, called the *axis* of perspectivity, and leaving invariant all the lines through a point P, called the *center* of perspectivity.

This definition is adapted from [Pamfilos](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/Perspectivity.html).  For more detail and background see [Hatton, *Projective Geometry*, Chapter IV](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n45/mode/2up), which uses the terms plane perspective and homology.

Given a point $P$, a line $p$, and points $X,X'$ such that $P,X,X'$ are collinear, there is a unique perspectivity $\mathbf P$ that maps $X$ to $X'$.  For a general point $Y$, write $\mathbf P(Y)$ as $Y'$ (similarly for line $\ell$ and its image $\ell'$).  Then, according to the definition,
$$
\begin{align}
&\bullet\;\;  \text{$P$ is on line $YY'$} \tag{$\star$} \\ 
&\bullet\;\; \text{$\ell,\ell'$ meet on $p$.} \tag{$\star\star$}
\end{align}
$$

Turning to the question, let $P$ be the given point, and $p$ the polar of $P$ with respect to $c$.  Then it is easy to show (using the geometry of polars) that the perspectivity $\mathbf P$ defined by $P,p,D,D'$ maps $c$ to itself, and in particular $E\to E',F->F',G->G'$.

The same is true for lines: $DE\to D'E'$. By ($\star\star$), $DE,D'E'$ meet on $p$.  In other words, $O=DE\cdot D'E'$ is on $p$ and similarly $N$ is on $p$.

$\mathbf P$ takes $L=DE\cdot FG$ to $M=L'=D'E'\cdot F'G'$. By ($\star$), $P$ is on line $LM$.  Similarly $P$ is on line $QR$, and we are done.

This is the conceptual proof I was looking for, and extends nicely to 3D.